# Implementation of string functions in Python?

Tags: python, string, implementation, pypy

Is there any documentation on how Python's string functions are implemented in Python?

I understand that str is a built-in module, and so its functions are implemented in C.
But isn't there code for it anyways?  How about in Pypy?  From what I've read so far, they've re-implemented a lot of built-in modules in Python itself.

Example Question: How is the split method of strings implemented?  (Without writing my own implementation of it)

EDIT: I am **not** looking for an implementation written in C (which is the default implementation in the source code of Python/CPython).

Comment: Python (including PyPy) is open source: to understand the implementation, just look at the implementation.

Comment: PyPy implements some builtins in Python. But most are written in RPython, which may or may not be more low-level than a Python implementation.

Comment: The default implementation of Python (CPython) uses C functions for the string functions, as I mentioned in my original post.  What I'm looking for is a Python implementation of these functions.

Comment: @delnan How compatible is RPython with Python code.  I've read that it's a subset - does this mean that Python will fully understand it?  Can I, for example, parse the AST of RPython code?

Comment: Yes, all RPython programs are valid Python programs (this is used to great effect for testing). My point is, due to the restrictions, they're not necessarily idiomatic or understandable. But thinking about it, RPython strings have at least some methods built-in (i.e. RPython programs don't need to define them, they're built into RPython), so maybe PyPy's implementation of Python strings mostly calls into these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question posed, it's just a bit too long to be a comment.

Some quick digging through the source shows that PyPy has two implementations of `split()`, [this high-level, readable version](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/default/pypy/rlib/rstring.py#cl-11) and [this lower-level version](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/default/pypy/rpython/rstr.py#cl-236), which appears to be the implementation of `split()` in rpython itself.

Neither of these implementations are equivalent to CPython's `split()` method (most obviously they do not handle the special case [CPython does](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/99f5a0475ead/Objects/stringobject.c#l1426) where the `sep` is not supplied). However, if you are merely interested in the basic algorithm used rather than the details, PyPy's implementations could be a guide (at a quick glance, it looks to be doing basically the same thing as both CPython and [Jython](https://bitbucket.org/jython/jython/src/8bc674cdfd2d/src/org/python/core/PyString.java#cl-1096)).

As a general resource, though, there's no reason to think that PyPy's implementation of all string functions would mirror the algorithms used in CPython -- PyPy is, after all, intended as an optimized version of Python running in a JIT, and this may have significant impact on what the most reasonable implementation of a method is (especially string functions, which frequently can be performance bottlenecks and which the implementors of an "optimized" runtime therefore have incentive to optimize).

Thinking about the more general question, there's very little incentive for the CPython developers to maintain a separate set of pure Python implementations of the low-level library already maintained in C. It seems that there is to much risk that the mirror implementations would grow stale or inaccurate to what is actually being done, which could ultimately be harmful for people who were trying to understand the inner workings of Python without reading the C code.

Comment: IF PyPy's implementation doesn't handle the case where the `sep` argument is omitted or `None`, then it's hardly what I would call a "compliant implementation". While I wouldn't be surprised if the algorithm wasn't the same, such differing functionality would (does).

Comment: @martineau: Admittedly, I'd be surprised if I hadn't missed something about how PyPy invokes `split()`, since the different functionality would be very unexpected. This was just what I found on a quick glance through.

Comment: the implementation used is in objspace/std/stringobject.py